# How to optimize a binary circuit?

Tags: circuit-design, optimization

I'm currently in the situation in which I need to optimize a binary circuit by reducing its number of gates. 
We regard a circuit simply as a directed acyclic graph with some input wires and some output wires. 
Some of the input wires may hold constants, and some other hold "variables".
Vertices contain gates which can be either `XOR` or `AND`.

The circuit appeared in a Computer Science context, not in a Electrical Engineering one.
We need to optimize our circuit by reducing its number of gates, so we started thinking of some approaches to achieve this task.
Researching online we discovered that this is a well-studied problem in Electrical Engineering, with a lot of software out there that aids in this direction.
However, as expected most of the documentation/information/blogs/etc are targeted towards electrical engineers, and they are overwhelming for outsiders who do not have the terminology.

For instance, I managed to gather from [here](https://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~nsmart/MPC/) the following steps

> ...We first created **flattened Verilog netlists**, we started from a purely combinational **HDL description** of the implementation. We used **Cadence Encounter RTL compiler** in conjunction with the **Faraday FSA0A_C 0.18 mm ASIC Standard Cell Library** for **synthesis**. For synthesis we flattened the **hardware modules hierarchy** and we allowed only the use of **INV1S, AN2, XOR2HS, TIE0, and TIE1 cells.** After this we re-wrote the output and topologically sorted the resulting circuits.

I have highlighted the terms that do not make sense to me, even after extensive searches online. Also, other sources I found that may help with this problem keep a similar notation and are hard to understand for an outsider.

Given the above, my question is

> Given a boolean circuit with only `XOR` and `AND` gates, what should be the starting point in order to minimize its number of gates?

Any recommendation on software, examples, terms, etc. is highly appreciated.

---

**Addendum**

I was suggested to provide more details on the problem I'm trying to solve here. I have a large binary circuit (to be explicit, this circuit is written in a file like [this one](https://homes.esat.kuleuven.be/~nsmart/MPC/sha-256.txt)), roughly 300K gates (as I said above, these are `XOR` or `AND` gates). 
I want to *algorithmically* minimize the size of this circuit so that it ends up with fewer gates. 
Morever, due to the context in which this circuit appeared, `AND` gates have a much higher cost than `XOR` gates.
Therefore, an optimization with a smaller number of `AND` gates is very much preferable (I think this may contrast with usual optimization in electrical engineering in which only the size matters without distinction on the different types of gates, but I may be wrong).

To receive more accurate answers I include a bit of my background for this problem.
I know about boolean logic and I can identify the optimization techniques that can be used for this purpose.
I have read about two-level and multi-level optimization (although I don't get the differences between the two).
I also know about the existence of algorithms like Esspreso and Quine–McCluskey.
Finally, I've read a bit about HDL and RTL languages and compilers, but I'm not even sure it's relevant.

My main issue here is that I don't know where to get started. Which of these concepts/tool fit better in my setting?

---

**Context of the question**

In case you're interested, here I add some details about the context where this question appeared.

The field is cryptography, a subdomain of computer science. 
More specifically, I'm talking about something called Multiparty Computation and Fully Homomorphic Encryption. 
The important point here is that we regard functions to be computed as circuits, or DAGs, where each vertex is an operation (either addition or multiplication). 
This is another way to say multivariate polynomials.
When this is done modulo 2 we're talking then about binary circuits with `AND` and `XOR` as the two allowed operations.

Now, the goal of these techniques is to be able to secretly compute some function over some data.
This is done by writing the function in terms of `XOR` and `AND` operations (so, a binary circuit or a very long boolean expression) and proceeding from the inputs to the outputs in an operation-by-operation fashion.

Due to the way these techniques work, each `AND` operation for us is *much more* expensive than an `XOR` operation.
This means that having equivalent representations for the same program with a smaller number of `AND` operations is much better, since it can be performed more efficiently. 
Moreover, having a very "deep" circuit is bad, so we also want to optimize to have a more shallow circuit (I hope these terms of "deep" and "shallow" make sense in this context).

My initial impression is that this problem could be similar to some problems faced in electrical engineering.
Is there any correlation?

---

**PS:** Please bear I mind that I come from Computer Science and hold no knowledge on Electrical Engineering at all, so this question may be silly, contain incorrect terminology, wrong tags, or even be off-topic, in which case I kindly ask you for a pointer to the right place to ask.

Comment: Do you mean optimizing the boolean logic? There are established rules for that from decades ago. Consult a logic design text book.

Comment: @Learner Thanks. Yes, I guess that is precisely what I want: optimizing the underlying boolean formula. Can you please point to a particular logic design textbook you consider relevant?

Comment: These are standard books. All are good. See which one is easier for your level. 
1- Digital Logic Design by Moris Mano, 2- Digital Design: Principles and Practices, John. F. Wakerly, 3- Digital Design: A Systems Approach by William J. Dally

Comment: Daniel, minimization doesn't have a single answer or process. There is a standard process for forming the sum of products or product of sums and there is software that can do this called [Espresso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espresso_heuristic_logic_minimizer). You can download the source for that, too, I think. An input to that process is whether or not you want to treat the outputs as isolated, or combined. But even with that, you also need to look up "two-level and three-level" minimization methods and also the "sum of pseudo-products." Those should get you started.

Comment: @jonk Thanks a lot for your useful comment Jonk. I just read a bit about these algorithms, you're right, these go along the lines of what I'm looking for.

I noticed that there seems to be a difference between two-level and multi-level optimizers. It's still not clear to me which one is preferrable in my scenario (large circuit, 300K gates, I want to minimize the number of gates)

Comment: @Daniel If you want to minimize the gates, then you need to define what a "gate" is to you (is a 5-in OR gate a gate to you?) Do you want to minimize space? Do you want to minimize combinatorial delay? XOR delay is NOT the same as AND gate delay, for example, but that also doesn't mean there aren't at least a dozen different approaches for XOR that have varying interesting properties with regard to fan-out,m fan-in, and gate delay based upon the approach and technology. And that's only one facet of the question. You need to craft a very careful definition of your question. The answers depend.

Comment: @Daniel Also, you may want to minimize terms. If so, you are looking at current research into multi-level optimization, Note that I'm saying "research" because this remains an active field of research and exploration. Clarity is not there to be had, as yet. However, things will get clearer to you as you dig into the research activities. If you are looking for "the one answer" then I think you will find yourself at the same kind of loss that Spice simulator coding authors find themselves in -- no single approach, just a collection of approaches where some work better than others, at times.

Comment: @Daniel In short, you need to develop a COMPREHENSIVE view, first. Once you've acquired that perspective, you ***may*** be then able to craft a precise question to ask. With that question in hand, you might be able to get more meaningful answers to it. Also be aware that in gaining a broader comprehension, you may find that there are natural "demarcations" in the problem that become clearer to you -- boundaries that the nature of the question itself show you, once you understand it better. These natural boundaries should be leveraged when asking your questions.

Comment: @jonk I really appreciate the comments. This is one of the issues that I warned in the question about me not coming from electrical engineering, nor the question being related to that field directly but more to computer science. The reason why I'm asking here is because I'm sure what I need can be found in this domain. A gate for us is an `XOR` or an `ADD` operation which only accepts two values as input and return one output. Unfortunately, I'm not sure about what the different types of delay you mention are

Comment: @jonk In less technical terms, what we need is a representation of the same circuit having (1) less multiplicative depth (perhaps this is what you know as AND delay?) and (2) a smaller number of AND gates in general. I'm really happy to dig deeper to be able to express my requirements in a better language, but I would need to hear first what, from my statement above, is ambiguous to begin with :) And thanks for taking the time!

Comment: @Daniel Perhaps if you were to expose the full context of your application subspace, it would help me (or us) prune away some thoughts and emphasize others. But I've no real clue about it. As I see it right now, I think you imagine gates as mathematical operations. But research is more about implementations, because that's what matters to people making practical devices. A "delay" is the mean time of how long it takes for a "a specified input change" (itself not instantaneous) to cause a corresponding "change in a specified output" (which itself isn't instantaneous.)

Comment: @jonk I get your point. Thanks for your willingness to help! You're right, I (and people in this field) regards gates as mathematical operations. We're thinking of this "circuit" object as simply a mathematical structure, and we want to find an equivalent one with different properties that are more convenient for us. Initially, I thought that this had a big correlation with the circuits considered in electrical engineering, and the optimization problems that are faced in that domain.

I have added details about this to the question, please feel free to read it and comment :)

Comment: @Daniel Your question is now ***much*** clearer. +1 because of that fact! Look into compiler tools -- the so-called "Dragon book" might be a start, but only a start. Clearly, you'll start out parsing into a tree and then apply procedures designed to re-arrange and re-order operations and to look for subtrees that can be folded, resulting in a DAG. However, the strategies you apply will have everything to do with the resulting DAG. I would imagine that you'd be more informed than most of us about salient research into your use of XOR and AND here. "Cost functions" will be important to know.

Comment: @Daniel If I were you, I'd go find researchers publishing in areas related to compiler development for FPGA and ASIC optimization, as well as just general compiler optimization for specialized computer systems, such as "VLIW" areas (the Bulldog compiler PhD thesis circa 1985 comes to mind, not as an answer but as the direction I'm pointing towards.) I'd then contact these researchers by email or phone, listen and follow up on their thoughts, and I think you will eventually find the right handful of people who can actually help you.

Comment: @jonk Thank you for the information. That Dragon book seems to be quite a big reference! But a good one to get myself started. Thank you also for the keywords, definitely a good starting point.

I encourage you to compile some of your comments as an answer. I would accept it and close this question :)

Comment: @Daniel to be clear, are you wanting to optimise a set of gates that you are emulating or are you investigating the creation of a real life circuit?  The same principles and algorithms could be used to manipulate the logical expressions that your gates represent, and as you are no doubt aware, the "costs" of different types of gates will vary, but also bear in mind that computer logic, because of its sequential nature and obedience to order of operations will by default eliminate many problems that may occur when you convert to a real life circuit with interference and propagation delay.

Comment: @KH We're not really interested in a "real-life" circuit, assuming that I'm getting correctly what you mean by that (i.e. a circuit to be implemented in an actual chip). What we want is an equivalent representation of a given circuit that has better properties, specifically, lower multiplicative depth. Now, the way we will "run" this circuit is a totally different story.

I suspected what you say that the same principles and algorithms could be useful for us, but I need to find about those and understand them first. I'll dive into the bibliography suggested in other comments/answers.

Answer (score 1):

A first place to go might be something called "boolean algebra". If you have only few boolean algebra terms, then you can do that by hand.

Example from school: (x+1)*(1+2)reduces to 3x+3

analogous...

(A xor B) * A reduces to A * not_B

You just have to learn the boolean algebraic rules. A place to start might be [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/bool_8.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Stefan. I'm ok with boolean algebra and with its simplification rules and so on. I mostly wanted to look at automated tools that can optimize the circuit for me, without me having to check manually for the existence of simplification opportunities

Comment: Ok. Maybe if you show us your problem, we can give you better advice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Stefan! I tried to add a bit more detail, please see the question body :)

Comment: Well, giving the size of the problem, this is a bit out of my league. But here is how I would approach it: You seem to know HDL, which is used for fitting logic into some FPGA devices. These compilers are very powerful in logic reduction, so I would try to transform your logic file into such a HDL file (VHDL or ABEL language) and feed that into the HDL Compiler of a FPGA toolchain. You might not get XOR preference over AND, but you will get reduction of terms.

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a very good starting point! I'm definitely going to try it out. Yes, I was not expecting to find the preference of XOR over AND in this domain to be honest, but just minimizing terms in general is very useful to me!

Answer (score 1):

| Defining some of these terms for you |
| --- |
| **flattened Verilog netlists** |
| HDL description |
| Cadence Encounter RTL compiler |
| **Faraday FSA0A_C 0.18 mm ASIC Standard Cell Library** |
| **synthesis** |
| **INV1S, AN2, XOR2HS, TIE0, and TIE1 cells** |

**flattened Verilog netlists** : [Hierarchichal netlist vs Flatten netlist?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/265990/hierarchichal-netlist-vs-flatten-netlist)

**Faraday FSA0A_C 0.18 mm ASIC Standard Cell Library** = This is a standard cell library which contains implementation and information for some basic boolean functions. For example, this library will hold an implementation of an inverter, which will have information about the size, drive strength, and possibly delays and SPICE Models of the gate.

For the names of the cell, I have the following table with basic information. The standard cell library will define details of each gate.

| Name | Function |
| --- | --- |
| INV1S | Inverter |
| AN2 | And gate |
| XOR2HS | XOR gate |
| TIE0 | Tie Low (set as logic 0) |
| TIE1 | Tie High (set as logic 1) |

**synthesis** : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_synthesis

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much to add to your quandary, but look into min- and max-terms as well. When combined with everything else aforementioned, sum of products and product of sums, you might have some ammo to shoot at Espresso with.

Your circuit is too large for conventional (i.e., "manual") diagrammatic breakdown or logic gate substitution, (emulating an AND with two NANDs, say.)

[image]

And for your case, while you can't make an AND with XORs, you *can* make an XOR with ANDs and NOTs (inverters).

[Build an XOR gate from AND/NOT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/487529/build-an-xor-gate-from-and-not)

Edit:

Oh, and in case it hasn't cropped up in your research yet, an ASIC is an "application-specific integrated circuit", a fancy acronym for a proprietary chip, essentially.