# Build an XOR gate from AND/NOT

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, logic-gates

is the following a legitimate way to create an xor gate?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRUct8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The AND with the two NOT inputs would be a NOR, but I'm seeing with just two gates -- AND + NOT -- if the below is a valid way to build an XOR gate or if I'm missing something. The above would eventually decompose into:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftL4Z5.png)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's a legitimate way with AND gates.

NAND or NOR gates are usually the primitives available so an XOR would be built from those in practice.

Comment: thanks. Could you please explain what you mean by "primitives" ? Why wouldn't the three basic gates be and/or/not, since those would be the most basic?

Comment: @David542 The availability of gates reflects the underlying electronic elements that are used to construct them. It so happens that NOR/NAND require less transistors to realize in typical processes/logic families such as CMOS, even though they aren't as "basic" from a purely logic analysis/design standpoint.

Comment: Hi David, NAND and NOR gates are primitives cuz they both can easily be produced from CMOS , this link explains fundementals-> http://www.vlsifacts.com/nand-gate-using-cmos-technology/.

Comment: It is also possible to reconstruct all possible logic gates just using several 2 input NAND or NOR gates.